# Custom sensor in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

Airflow Version : 1.10.0

Following [this guide](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-importing-custom-hooks-operators/) I have created `sensors` folder and `my_sensor.py`, I have added the import and use of the

```
[...]
from sensors.my_sensor import MySensor

[...]
wait_something = MySensor(task_id='taskA')
[...]
```

Unfortunately Airflow complains when trying to reload the DAG, as follows:

> Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] No module named 'sensors'

I have also restarted the server just to be sure.

The following sentence (from the aforementioned guide) makes me wonder if I failed to update this `PATH` variable, but I cannot find it anywhere and I have no clue:

> When Airflow is running, it will add dags/, plugins/, and config/ to PATH

PS: I don't want to use `Plugins`, the point of that guide is to provide an alternative way to load custom operators/sensors/hooks *without* using `Plugins`

Answer (score 1):

The guide you reference appears to have been incorrect. `PATH` is the environment variable that lists a set of paths that is searched for executables like the Python executable, `grep`, or `vim`. `PYTHONPATH` is the environment variable that Python uses to add to its module search path. What Airflow is most likely updating is `sys.path` which is the module search path at runtime, which will include Python's regular module directories as well as the contents of `PYTHONPATH`. `sys.path` is particularly useful because it is user-mutable at runtime.

To check what your module search path looks like you could add this to the top of your DAG:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Even in cases of broken DAGs if that section is the first part of the script, then the `print` output will be included in the webserver/scheduler's DAG parsing log. You can also check the default `sys.path` without any Airflow changes by running a command like:

```
# python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Now, you may not have permission to write files to system directories like `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`, or to be able to restart Airflow with a custom `PYTHONPATH`. But another option is to place your custom sensor in a directory that you do have write access to, and update the `sys.path` before that path is imported in your DAG. Something like this:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/some/arbitrary/path/plugins")

from sensors.my_sensor import MySensor
# ...do something with MySensor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```py
from airflow.sensors.sftp_sensor import SFTPSensor
    
# where sftp_sensor is my name and sensor is SFTPSensor. 
    
class SFTPSensorPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "sftp_sensor"
    sensors = [SFTPSensor]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'd rather avoid using Plugin as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and it turned out that I hadn't mounted my plugins folder into my container. Once I mounted it all worked.